# sbt build failed in Intellij but I want to open the project anyways

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to import an existing sbt project. As part of the import process IJ attempts to build it. The sbt build fails - and it is due to proxy issues not the culprit of IJ. I want to open the project with existing sources anyways..but am unable to figure out how to do so .  When hitting "Finish" in the "import Project" dialog, IJ will do the build.Is there a "skip build" option somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the most reliable way to handle sbt projects in IJ is to actually open the file directly from the Finder (mac) / Explorer (windoze) / nautilus (linux/gnome).

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you may try to generate intellij files from sbt using

```
sbt gen-idea
```

or

```
sbt idea
```

(the exact command depends on the sbt configuration)
It's always worked for me. I'm using the cmomunity edition.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of those as workarounds.  We have proxy issues that prevent sbt from working properly.